# BASH, if statement with three conditions

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm new to BASH and I have to write a BASH file.

I have this if statement

```
if [[ ${disp} != ?(-)+([0-9]) ]] || [[ $disp -ne 1 ]] || [[ $disp -ne 0 ]]
    then
        echo -e "Parametro disponibilidade tem que ser '0' ou '1'!"
        echo -e "disponivel - 1, indisponivel - 0" 
        exit 1
fi
```

The second and the third conditions don't work. However if I delete the last condition

```
if [[ ${disp} != ?(-)+([0-9]) ]] || [[ $disp -ne 1 ]]
    then
        echo -e "Parametro disponibilidade tem que ser '0' ou '1'!"
        echo -e "disponivel - 1, indisponivel - 0" 
        exit 1
fi
```

The last condition works!!
Can't someone explain me why this happens and how would you do it?

It should check if the user input is an integer and that integer must be 0 or 1, else bash exits

Thanks for your help

Comment: Many beginners confuse "or" and "and"; is that the problem here? Can you show some values of `$disp` which don't work like you expect?

Comment: `[[ ${disp} != ?(-)+([0-9]) ]]` looks like you are trying to use extended globs; are you sure this feature is enabled in your script?

Comment: Also, with `[[ ... ]]`, you can use the boolean operators inside the condition, i.e. `[[ $disp != ?(-)+([0-9]) || $disp -ne 1 || $disp -ne 0 ]]`

Comment: if $disp==0 or $disp==1 the bash exits

Comment: [[ ${disp} != ?(-)+([0-9]) ]] works fine, i'm just checking if the user input other than integers. user must input 0 or 1, else bash exits

Comment: Note that at least one of the conditions `[[ $disp -ne 1 ]]` and `[[ $disp -ne 0 ]]` will always be true, so the `then` block will always be executed.  You probably need `[[ $disp -ne 1 && $disp -ne 0 ]]` to test for 0 or 1.  I'm not sure about the first term, but (as alluded to by @tripleee), confusion over 'and' vs 'or' is quite common, especially with negated conditions in the separate terms.

Comment: Exactly, that was my problem. thank you so much. It's solved